# How Do I Make Transparent Navbar Have Background Color After Scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to give my navbar the effect of being transparent initially, but upon scrolling is given a black background color. I understand that Javascript is best suited for the job, but I have tried `window.addEventListener` and have remained unsuccessful. Any tips at all are greatly appreciated.

```js
<script>
        window.addEventListener( 'scroll', function () {
            let nav = document.querySelector('nav');

            nav.classList.toggle('scrolling-active');
        });
    </script>
```

```css
#header {
  height: 100vh;
}

#header nav {
  display: flex;
  background-color: transparent;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
}


#header nav .name {
  display: flex;
  width: fit-content;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 30px;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}

#header nav .name span {
  color: rgb(182, 18, 18);
}

#header nav ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  width: fit-content;
}

#header nav ul li {
  padding: 30px;
}

#header nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Yanone Kaffeesatz", sans-serif;
}

.scrolling-active {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
        <section class="hero">
            <nav class="nav">
                <div class="name"><h1><span>D</span>ave <span>A</span>nthony</h1></div>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Recent Posts</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this comes down to CSS specificity.  You have this in your css:

```
#header nav {
  display: flex;
  background-color: transparent;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

`id`s are more specific than classes and have higher importance so it will use this background color, which is transparent.  One way to solve it is by adding an `!important` clause to your added class:

```
.scrolling-active {
  background-color: black !important;
}
```

However, this isn't the best approach since it doesn't really need it if you just simply rework your ID usage (but it will work).

Comment: I deleted the #header and just left nav as my selector and it started to work!

Comment: sweet!  If you don't know about specificity in CSS or just need a refresher, check out here: https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/ .